# Primes of the form $a^2 + 5b^2$

Tags: number-theory

How do I check if a number $m \bmod 20$ can be written in the form $a^2 + 5b^2$?

I am trying to prove that if the prime $p = a^2 + 5b^2$ then $p \equiv 1\text{ or }9 \pmod{20}$ and the only way I know how is to check each case from $p\equiv 1 \pmod{20}$ to $19 \pmod{20}$ and show that only $1$ and $9$ works. If there's a simpler way please share. Thanks!

Comment: For a prime, do you really need to consider all 20 cases? E.g., can a prime be congruent to 6 mod 20?